# Defining Type in Controller RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, object, controller

I am trying to find a way for my controller to define an object as `@jobs` only when the job type is equal to 'creative' - once I have defined this correctly I should then be able to call instances of @jobs in my views.

At the moment I have

```
def creative
  @creative = Job.where(params[:type] == 'creative')
  @jobs = @creative.where('created_at > ?', 30.days.ago).reverse
end
```

I am sure there is a very simple and quick answer to this but I can't seem to find the right way to define it.

Any help really would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to define a scope in the model:

```
class Job < ...
  scope :creative, where(type: 'creative')
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@jobs = Job.creative.where(...)
```

Comment: Perfect application of "fat model - skinny controller".